# Operation Not Permitted on /usr/local/, Homebrew cannot be installed

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

Looking for some guidance on how to fix my permissions on my `/usr/bin` directory. I actually recently had a data recovery on my machine where I had to have my whole home directory copied to a new mac.

Upon this I noticed that my old binaries I had in my `/usr/local` folder prior to my migrating my data are no longer able to be ran.

I also do not have `brew`, and I am unable to install it.

Attempting to `chown` `/usr/local` also fails

```
% sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

This first started happening when I noticed brew is not installed. When I try to install brew, I get the following:

```
% /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin
mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Not a directory
mkdir: /usr/local/sbin: Not a directory
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin
```

Here is my `ls -aleO@ /usr/local`

````
total 52960
drwxr-xr-x  14 root             wheel  sunlnk                 448 Feb 24 19:19 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root             wheel  restricted,hidden      352 Feb 18 16:51 ..
    com.apple.rootless         0 
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 Caskroom
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 Cellar
drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 Frameworks
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 myuser.user  admin  -                 12434524 Feb 23 21:11 bin
    com.apple.quarantine          57 
drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 etc
drwxr-xr-x  20 myuser.user  admin  -                      640 Feb 16 11:12 go
drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 include
drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 lib
drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser.user  admin  -                       64 Feb 24 19:19 opt
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 myuser.user  admin  -                 14033312 Feb 23 21:44 sbin
    com.apple.quarantine          57 
drwxrwxr-x   3 myuser.user  admin  -                       96 Feb 24 19:19 share
drwxrwxr-x   3 myuser.user  admin  -                       96 Feb 24 19:19 var```
````

Comment: You've tagged this nix, but it feels like Mac. You cannot chown  folders on the boot drive if you're on Catalina or Big Sur.

Comment: I understand this, the problem is, I cannot install anything using brew. I cannot put any executables in my /usr/bin path to run them from any directory because I do not have the rights to. Brew also cannot be installed due to this issue as well.

Comment: You have no rights to any folder on the boot partition if you are on Catalina or Big Sur… which you have yet to clarify.

Comment: Correct, but yes I am on Catalina. But prior to me migrating my data, (same OS) I had brew installed, and I had the ability to run executables from this path.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin. After doing so I was able to install homebrew. It looks like I had existing symlinks to this directory.

Comment: If this works for you, you should accept it as the answer.